# How to create composable IAM policies with AWS provider in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm starting to move to terraform from some in-house scripts. In my current setup, I have sets of IAM policy statements that I combine together to create a single IAM role. Some of these are templates. I'm not sure how to achieve similar deduplication in terraform.

The [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html) data source is almost what I want, but it only allows a single `source_json`.

The best thing I can come up with is have data sources for all of the components, and then do something like:

```
dynamic "statement" {
  for_each = concat(set1, set2, set3, set4, ...)
  content {
      sid = statement.sid
      actions = statement.actions
      resources = statement.resources
      ...
  }
}
```

But that is kind of messy, and I would need to repeat the this definition for each iam role, and I'm actually not sure how the references would work if one of the fields is undefined (for example, if it doesn't have an Sid)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not creating multiple [aws_iam_role_policy](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy.html) resources and attaching them to the same role?

Comment: Oh, i guess that would work in most cases. The exception is if there are more than 10, since I would hit the limit on policies attached to a role